# Search dynamic array index MongoDB

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I'm relatively new to MongoDB and trying to figure out how to search for data which has dynamic keys, my dataset is below:

```
[
    'id' => '60bb040f7e589378f644f9a2',
    'name' => 'foo',
    'settings' => [
        'foo' => [
            'type' => 'custom',
            'enabled' => 'yes'
        ],
        'bar' => [
            'type' => 'custom',
            'enabled' => 'no'
        ],
        'baz' => [
            'type' => 'custom',
            'enabled' => 'no'
        ]
    ]
]
```

I want to get the search inside `settings`, and get all the settings which has enabled as `yes`.

I've tried this

```
return Customer::raw(function($collection) {
    return $collection->aggregate([
        [
            '$search' => [
                "wildcard" => [
                    'query' => 'yes',
                    'path' => 'settings.*.enabled'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
});
```

I am getting the following errror:

> Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$search'

I've also tired using $match, like this

```
Customer::raw(function($collection)
    {
        return $collection->aggregate([
            [
                '$match' => [
                    "settings.*.enabled" => 'yes'
                ]
            ],
        ]);
    })
```

But it does't return any value.

Any direction on achieving this will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know the `$search` aggregation stage is only available when using MongoDB Atlas Search and only when you create a search index .  Are you following any documentation or guide that uses this syntax?

Comment: Nothing as of now. Just some googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is a bit complex but is all I can come up with myself:

```
Customer::raw(function($collection)
    {
        return $collection->aggregate([
            [
                '$addFields' => [
                    "settingsArray" => [
                          '$objectToArray' => '$settings'
                     ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$unwind' => [
                     'path' => '$settingsArray'
                 ]
            ],
            [
                 '$match' => [
                       'settingsArray.v.enabled' => 'yes'
                  ]
            ],
            [ '$unset' => 'settingsArray' ],
            [
                 '$group' => [
                      '_id' => '$_id', 
                      doc => [ '$first' => '$$ROOT' ]
                 ]
            ],  
            [
                '$replaceRoot' => [ 
                    'newRoot' => '$doc'
                ]
            ] 
        ]);
    });
```

This should return all documents with at least one enabled setting.

A key point about aggregation is that the pipeline works on all documents that the previous stage of the pipeline returned.
Here's the aggregation pipeline explanation:

1. `$addFields` will convert the settings object to an array of format `[ { k: key, v: value } ]` e.g. `[ { k: 'foo', 'v': { type: 'custom', enabled: 'yes' } }, ... ]`
2. `$unwind` will "unwind" the document and "replace" it with X copies of the same document one for each entry in the newly added `settingsArray` array. The `settingsArray` at this stage is not an array anymore but a single entry of type `{ k: key, v: value }`. In short you'd get one document per setting
3. `$match` will do the actual matching for any document with an enabled setting (remember now each document will only have a single setting as `settingsArray`
4. `$unset` will remove the settingsArray from each document bringing it back to its original format
5. `$group` will group all documents by their `_id` and use the first result of each group as a `doc` entry. Each document will now be like `{ _id: <id>, doc: <original document> }`
6. `$replaceRoot` will set the root of the document to `doc` and therefore bring the documents back to their original format.

Would love to hear if anyone else has a better solution here.

Comment: Looks like, it is complicated than expected. But when I run this query I am getting this error: `Invalid $project :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'."`

Comment: That may have been a mistake in `$unset`. Give it a try now

Comment: Working, I made some modification and added concat to the pipeline, which makes only concatenated values to show up. How do I retain the document even after concatenation?

Comment: @Rehan I can't know for sure. Need to be wary that when you modify or filter something in the aggregation pipeline then any older state of the thing is lost. If it's one thing you should keep in mind is that each aggregation step just takes the previous step's outputted documents as input to generate its output so a step can't reference documents outputted by previous steps. There's no sense of "this result belongs to the document X from the previous step" unless you define this in the pipeline step yourself. Otherwise it's all pretty blind